# AngularJS MVC Razor - How does one define a single controller in multiple files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC application that has a master layout that has a @RenderBody() inside of it that renders the body of the individual page. In the master layout I have given the body tag an angularjs app name and controller name.

I want the controller to be defined in a separate global angular.js file. This will share common functions that every page can take advantage of.

```
 myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {    
          $scope.sharedFunction = //...shared function stuff
})';
```

I also want to add specific scope functions and variables in the child pages in MVC. When I get to the child pages, I believe I end up redefining the controller if I use the same syntax.

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {    
      $scope.showOverlay = false;
}]);
```

How can I make it so the same controller that is defined in the body gets page specific items added to it in the child pages that are rendered using @RenderBody()?

Comment: This is not an ASP.NET MVC concern. You need to set up your Angular code accordingly. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#scope-inheritance-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by nesting ng-controllers. The second controller inherited all of the first controller functions and I was able to overwrite them and add to them in the second controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your 'app' as a module in Angular, like so:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [myController])
```

The 2nd part of the declaration allows you to pass in an array of 'dependencies' that your Angular app relies on. In this case, your app will include your 'myController' controller

Then use this attribute on the part of your html that you want Angular to act upon:

```
ng-app="app"
```

Doing this will make your controller available to any page that utilises your 'app' module.

Comment: So lets say I define the main controller in a script file that always gets imported. I import it and set the dependency like you show for that page. How can I then add $scope.showOverlay = false to that controller that would only exist for the page I'm on and not all? All the other pages that use the script will have access to $scope.sharedFunction but not the overlay as that was only added on one page.